# Jupyter lab is only opened on private ip, not public ip

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, jupyter, ubuntu-18.04, jupyter-lab

OS : ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on aws ec2

I'm setting up jupyter lab on my aws ec2 server, and want to connect my server from other pc.

However I can't access jupyter

Maybe that's why it is connected to private ip

Firstly, I installed jupyter and config

```
$ pip3 install jupyter

$ pip3 install jupyterlab

$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

changed config on

> "~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py"

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'

c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'

c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False

c.NotebookApp.password = <my_password>

c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

and then, I try to run jupyter lab

> $ jupyter lab

Finally,

```
[I 06:25:39.565 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab

[I 06:25:39.565 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab

[W 06:25:39.567 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...

[I 06:25:39.569 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab

[I 06:25:39.569 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab

[I 06:25:39.570 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu/.certs

[I 06:25:39.570 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:

[I 06:25:39.570 LabApp] http://(ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX or 127.0.0.1):8888/

[I 06:25:39.570 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

is printed

I expect `ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com` shows on cmd

How can I run jupyter on public ip?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: I have provided a solution to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636501/3390419