# Running jupyter notebook on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, python-poetry, aws-cloud9

I have a cloud 9 instance set up on my AWS account. I am using poetry as my package manager and have installed jupyter notebook.

When I run the command `poetry run jupyter notebook` it runs as it usually does, but when I press the links they say that the site can't be reached.

Some things I have noticed is that in some AWS documentation there is mention of using port 8080, I have tried that but it doesn't work.

I also see something about http vs https, so could it be that it won't display because the link is not https?

Regardless any help on how to open up a notebook running on the cloud 9 instance would be very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the notebook over HTTP:

```
export PWD="MyPassword" # choose whatever password you want

jupyter notebook --generate-config
echo "conf = get_config()" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "conf.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "from IPython.lib import passwd" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "password = passwd('${PWD}')" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.NotebookApp.password = password"  >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "conf.NotebookApp.port = 8888" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
jupyter notebook
```

then hit `http://public-ip-address:8888` and login with the password you specified.

---

If you want to access the notebook over HTTPS (with a self-signed certificate):

```
export PWD="MyPassword" # choose whatever password you want

export DNS=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /home/ec2-user/mykey.key -out /home/ec2-user/mycert.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=$DNS"
jupyter notebook --generate-config
echo "conf = get_config()" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "conf.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "from IPython.lib import passwd" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "password = passwd('${PWD}')" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "c.NotebookApp.password = password"  >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
echo "conf.NotebookApp.port = 8888" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
jupyter notebook --certfile=/home/ec2-user/mycert.pem --keyfile /home/ec2-user/mykey.key
```

then hit `https://public-ip-address:8888` and login with the password you specified.

---

In either case, make sure that port `8888` is allowed in the EC2 security group and network ACL.